# Create own controls in visual webgui

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-web-gui

I want to create a button 'numeric only' in visual webgui (and i dont want to use masked textbox).

I did that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.80).aspx
This solution works in WinForms but doesn't work in WebGui. I have to delivered from Gizmox control TextBox of course.

So.. I have tried to create a textbox, with sets property `Text="OK"`, every time focus is lost. 
Like that:

```
using Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms;

namespace MyControls
{
    public partial class NumTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public NumTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "OK";
        }


    }
}
```

Why it doesn't work? 
Please help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public partial class NumTextBox : TextBox
{
    public NumTextBox()
    {
        LostFocus += new EventHandler(NumTextBox_LostFocus);
    }

    private void NumTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "OK";
    }
}
```

But note that vwg is a strange place. All your c# code is executed server side so such numeric text box might generate some unwanted traffic. Maybe you will be better of with this:

```
new TextBox { Validator = TextBoxValidation.IntegerValidator };
```

which will suppress not numeric characters from being added to textbox.